# How copy & paste over 1000 emails into an Email group?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I have a saved email that I use to email my staff. the email is sent to an email group that I created with over 1000+ email addresses. But alot of the email addresses are no longer valid.

I tried updating the email group and resending the email. But I still keep getting non-valid email returns when sending the emails. **How can I make a new email group without adding them all one-by-one?**

I'm using outlook 2010 and I can't find a way to do this. In order to delete the non-valid recipients, I have to expand my email list. Afterwards I can't collapse it back, so I'm unable to save it w/ the non-valid recipients removed.

Answer (score 0):

Question is better suited to https://superuser.com/.

Seems to me you could more easily delete some names from the distributon list but not from the "To" line in an email.

Open from Contacts as described here. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/create-and-edit-a-distribution-list-HA010205427.aspx#BM2